# Drawing a circle inside another circle canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I am trying to draw a gear in Canvas but running into issues from the start. I want to have a filled circle with a hallowed out middle. Instead, I am getting what looks to be an outline of a single circle.

Here is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d"),
i = 0;

function drawGear(){

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.translate(50,50);
    ctx.arc(0,0,20,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";;
    ctx.arc(0,0,5,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
}

drawGear();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/te3jn/

I believe that the issue is something related to the globalCompositeOperation, but I tried several of them (source-over, source-atop, destination-over) and none seem to work the way I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should begin a new path when drawing the second circle, like this:

```
ctx.fill();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFF";
// ...
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nYXzx/).

Without this, you'll essentially redraw both circles - the inner and the outer one - with the second `fill` call (check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abHGH/) for demonstration)